# How to conditionally use a development or production environment variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, config, dotenv

I'm receiving this error when I start my node application:

`ReferenceError: DEV_MAIL_HOST is not defined`

The following code works, when I'm specifically defining which env variable to use.

```
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
   host: process.env.DEV_MAIL_HOST,
   port: process.env.DEV_MAIL_PORT,
   auth: {
     user: process.env.DEV_MAIL_USER,
     pass: process.env.DEV_MAIL_PASSWORD
   }
 });
```

However, I'm trying to conditionally inject env variables based on what mode Node starts up in.

```
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? DEV_MAIL_HOST : LIVE_MAIL_HOST,
  port: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? DEV_MAIL_PORT : LIVE_MAIL_PORT,
  auth: {
    user:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? DEV_MAIL_USER : LIVE_MAIL_USER,
    pass:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
        ? DEV_MAIL_PASSWORD
        : LIVE_MAIL_PASSWORD
  }
});
```

Here's is my package.json, where I define which mode to start in.

```
 } 
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -e js,graphql -x  NODE_ENV=production node src/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon -e js,graphql -x NODE_ENV=development node --inspect src/index.js",
 }
}
```

What am I missing here?

**Fixed thanks to @MadWard's comment. I needed to destructure my environment variables.**

Comment: You're getting that error because the `DEV_MAIL_HOST` variable isn't defined in the scope of that code. Do you have a variable with that name somewhere in your code? If so, you haven't shown us.

Comment: Where are all your uppercase variables (such as `DEV_MAIL_HOST`) declared? From the code you posted, none of them is initialized or even declared as a variable, which Node seems to agree with.

Comment: `DEV_MAIL_HOST`, as well as all the rest of my env variables are declared in my .env file. index.js is where I am requiring the module `require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env" });`

Comment: `dotenv` only loads the variables into `process.env`, you still need to either call the variables by their name in process.env (`process.env.DEV_MAIL_HOST`) or set them as constants (`const DEV_MAIL_HOST = process.env.DEV_MAIL_HOST`).

Comment: Yah I needed to destructure the variables. @MadWard's comment fixed the issue for me. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From both snippets and the error that is shown, you appear to be using variables without declaring them first.

Either use the variables directly by their full name (`process.env.DEV_MAIL_HOST`, etc.), or initialize them at the beginning of your code:

```
const { 
    DEV_MAIL_HOST, 
    DEV_MAIL_PORT, 
    DEV_MAIL_USER,
    DEV_MAIL_PASSWORD,
    LIVE_MAIL_HOST, 
    LIVE_MAIL_PORT, 
    LIVE_MAIL_USER, 
    LIVE_MAIL_PASSWORD
} = process.env;
```

Comment: For sure! Don't hesitate to interpret Node errors literally at first: if the engine is telling you the variable is not defined, spend some time to figure out how that could be.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the correct way to declare environment variables. You should declare an environment variable like: MAIL_HOST

.env file should be different for each environment. In dev .env file MAIL_HOST should contain the development URL and in production .env file MAIL_HOST should contain the production URL

You can choose the env file by using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) library by using

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Comment: Ok, I assumed that there was one .env file with both prod and dev environment keys, and you could conditionally inject which keys to use based on the node environment. 

@MadWard's comment worked for me, but if I am not using dotenv files as they are intended, I will create a separate .env for my local machine and one for the server.